# Design logical model of Datawarehouse, Fact Tables and Dimensions Table

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, fact-table

Hi i'm newbie in Datawarehousing,For homework ask me realize the logical design, physical and implementation.How would you model this in a Data Warehouse:

i wish design the Data Warehouse which  give the answers of statistics relating to a baseball league

For players

in offensive:

> •How many times has a batter to bat.
>
> •How many runs scored is.
>
> •How many hits,doubles hit and triples hits.
>
> •How many homeruns did.
>
> •many  RBI.
>
> •many base on balls

in Defensive:

> ▪ How many outs, double play takes
>
> ▪ How many assists has
>
> ▪ How many errors lead or Pitcher:
>
> ▪ How many games has lost
>
> ▪ has won many games
>
> ▪ How many saved games
>
> ▪ How many complete games leads
>
> ▪ How many games have started many
>   times it has bleaching
>
> ▪ How many hit, double hit received, received triple hit, received homerun

As for the data of the players, it is important that this can be viewed as
season, Does anyone know some references on that precise part of DW design ? Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step in designing any data warehouse is to choose a business process. You have already done so by identifying reporting requirements based on baseball statistics, which is already a very well defined process (based on the rules of the game).

The second step is to identify the grain. The grain is the lowest level of detail you need to represent in reporting queries. For your baseball game situation, this would most likely be a pitch.

Next, you would identify the dimensions required to describe your grain. These are all easily identifiable - game, pitcher, batter and played date are obvious ones to start with.

Finally, you would identify the facts that hold measures relating to these dimensions. This encompasses many of the measures from your question, including whether a run was scored - which would be additive across any combination of dimensions, i.e. at inning, game, team, player, or season levels.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM Redbooks have a couple of titles that are on point.

- [Data Modeling Techniques for Data
  Warehousing](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg242238.html?Open)
- [Dimensional Modeling: In a Business
  Intelligence Environment](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247138.html?Open)