# Working with complex SQL Server database schemas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design

I have a database, I have to maintain compatibility with SQL Server 2005 and I've been thinking about ways to reduce complexity and deal with performance issues.

My database is like most other's and filled with data, it's a lot of data and there's a lot of queries in there to. I have many stored procedures that have been evolving (for some time now) to meet business demands. And this is mostly fine, but I'm running into performance problems and my queries are becoming increasingly complex to manage.

At a first glance, I don't think there's anything wrong with my data model, it's not absurdly normalized (we already denormalize some things), yet I find myself not being able to write and run those blazing fast queries for powering my web interface AJAX queries because all the constraints that seems to somewhat haphazardly exist here and there.

So, I've thought about it, and I think I want to organize my database in rings. Let me explain.

- Basically, in the inner most ring, you'll find the most specialized
  set of data. These tables are completely denormalized and have been
  built by aggregating data from outer rings to make sure specific
  queries run really fast.
- The outer most ring is ideally "dumb" and is basically just a really
  bad place to put things.
- Between outer and inner is basically your conceptual model, these
  pull from the other rings or push to the inner rings and this is
  where you clean your data and make sure that it's correct.
- Data can only flow from an outer ring to an inner ring.
- I don't want to use triggers to keep the different rings consistent, instead I have a services and jobs that, listen, poll and run at regular intervals to ensure eventual consistency, cross the board.

Now, this is where I ask for advice and hope to get some input from experienced database people. It's my belief that I could get more out of my database this way. And it will allow me to address both complexity and performance issues at different stages. Maybe there's a common name for what I'm doing or maybe this is what the NoSQL movement is all about, but I don't know really, the idea has some appeal to me, but if I'm way out there, I'd like to hear about it before I make a mistake...

Comment: IF you want speed and eventual consistency, a NoSQL solution may be a better choice.  Some of  this sounds like a roll-your-own nosql solution using SQL Server which just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Watch your language young man

Comment: @JNK - Let's just say that jumping ship and abandoning SQL Server isn't going to happen. Moreover, I'm not displeased at all of the way SQL Server does things, treated the right way, it get's things done. In the long run maybe NoSQL is the right choice, but I'm not there yet...

Comment: @JohnLeidegren - I'm by no means a NoSQL advocate (I don't know a ton about the different platforms yet), but when I hear eventual consistency I think of NoSQL.  NoSQL is **B** asically **A** vailable, **S** oft state, **E** ventual consistency, instead of **ACID**.

Comment: Yeah, but NoSQL is also not queryable efficiently. What you have in the core is an LAP database - whether you go ROLAP or not is another question. Most people (and you seem to fall into this) advocate NoSql because tehy can not wrap their head around the possibility of Cobbs relational theorem to start with. Bad choice (I cook spaghetti because I never managed cooking meat). You may be surpsrised that the spcail databases for reporting are mostly "NoSql" for years, but also NOT document oriented.

Comment: Just to clean up a bit, he's name was Codd, and it's called Codd's theorem...

Answer (score 1):

Although I basically agree with @TomTom's answer, I would phrase it differently: you have essentially developed the concept of the data warehouse (or data mart, to be specific) on your own. Buying a book on data warehousing is a great idea; attending a seminar or series of classes on the topic is even better. You've obviously done some serious thinking about this already and that will serve you well when you learn about best practices and the different approaches that have been developed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a beginner b ook into databases. Seriously. Split it into an OLTP and an OLAP part - a data warehouse is in order. Get rid of the stored procedures. Then realize that your "lot of odata" is likely other peoples "jokes of data" - I work on a sysstem supposed to scale to around 60tb of data (that is 60.000) - our initial hardware has 21.000 gigabyte.

Your system sonds like you mix up a normal database (OLTP) with a data warehouse. Split them - this wont work. Split them ALSO IN HARDWARE. This is total standard - geta  book about data warehouses.

Comment: IBM Redbooks have titles on designing and building data warehouses free to download. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178330/design-logical-model-of-datawarehouse-fact-tables-and-dimensions-table/6178657#6178657

Comment: I need an introduction to data warehousing (OLTP and OLAP), not sure I need a beginners book about databases. Thanks for pointing that out though. My problem is as real as any, doesn't mean I have to go all the way and scale up to TB of data, we don't really have any big work loads just a lot of data, complexity and slow queries but before it really becomes an issue, I'm looking into ways to redeem the situation.

Comment: So what? Sorry - big amounts of data + slow queires = better hwardware + standard approaches.

Comment: At least in a OLTP/OLAP situation you have two places where the data sits idly. Then huge amounts of processing pushing the data from one place to the another. It's a clearly, a defined process.