# my script on cakephp3 is too long to load

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make my own function and I don't understand why it's takes too much time to load.

If someone could help?

I want to notice that the other function like list, edit or add customer run well.

This is my code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Collection\Collection;

/**
 * Customer Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\CustomerTable $Customer
 */
class CustomerController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */



    /**
    *Login method
    *
    *@param string|null $login Customer login
    *@param string|null  $pasword Customer password
    *@return true Redirects to \connection index
    */
    public function login()
    {
        //$this->layout = 'default2';

        // Si vous accédez à la session plusieurs fois,
        // vous voudrez probablement une variable locale.
        $session = $this->request->session();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $query = $this->Customer->find('all', [
                /*'CustLogin' => $this->request->data['login'],
                'CustPassword' => $this->request->data['password'],*/
                'conditions' => [
                    'Customer.CustLogin ' => $this->request->data['login'],
                    'Customer.CustPassword ' => $this->request->data['password']
                ]
            ]);
            $row = $query->first();
        //debug($row);
            if(count($row) == 1){
                $customer = $row->toArray();
                $this->set('customer', $customer);
                $session->write('customer_session', $customer);
                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                $this->setAction('dashboard');
            }else{
                $this->Flash->error('Votre username ou mot de passe est incorrect.');
            }


        }


    }

    /**
    *logout method to disconnect customer
    *
    */

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->request->session()->destroy();
        $this->redirect('/customer/login');
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        $session = $this->request->session();
        if(isset($session) && !empty($session)){

            $customer = $session->read('customer_session');
            if( isset($customer) && !empty($customer) )
            {
                $this->set('customer', $customer);
                //$this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);

                //************on doit recuperer son credit
                $this->loadModel('Credits');
                $query = $this->Credits->find('all', [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'Credits.AccID ' => $customer['CustIdCredit']
                    ]
                ]);
                $row = $query->first();
                $this->set('credit', $row->toArray());

                //******************on recherche les sms inbound du jour
                $yesterday = strtotime('yesterday midnight');
                $today = strtotime('today midnight'); //on recupère le jour
                $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow midnight');
                $aujourdhui = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $today)); //. ' - Today for example purposes<br />';
                $demain = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $tomorrow));
                $hier = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $yesterday));
                //echo '/**********aujourdhui start $aujourdhui on and end on $demain ****/';
                //var_dump($aujourdhui);//******** date d aujourd'hui
                //var_dump($demain);//********* date de demain
                //echo '/**********this week start on $ceweekd and end on $ceweeke ****/';
                $this_week_start = strtotime("this week midnight");
                $next_week_start = strtotime("next week midnight");
                $ceweekd = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_week_start));
                $ceweeke = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $next_week_start));//******this week end on next week start
                //var_dump($ceweekd);
                //var_dump($ceweeke);
                //echo '/**********last week start on $ceweekld and end on $ceweekle ****/';
                $last_week_start = strtotime("last week midnight");
                //$last_week_end = strtotime("last week, +6 days");
                $ceweekld = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $last_week_start));
                $ceweekle = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_week_start));
                //var_dump($ceweekld);
                //var_dump($ceweekle);
                //echo '/**********this month start on $cemonthd and end on $cemonthe ****/';
                $this_month_start = strtotime("first day of this month midnight");
                $next_month_start = strtotime("first day of next month midnight");
                $cemonthd = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_month_start));
                $cemonthe = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $next_month_start));//******this month end on next month start
                //var_dump($cemonthd);
                //var_dump($cemonthe);
                //echo '/**********last month start on $cemonthld and end on $cemonthle ****/';
                $last_month_start = strtotime("first day of last month midnight");
                //$last_week_end = strtotime("last week, +6 days");
                $cemonthld = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $last_month_start));
                $cemonthle = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_month_start));
                //var_dump($cemonthld);
                //var_dump($cemonthle);



                //*****************on selectionne toutes les conncetions utilisateur
                $this->loadModel('Connection');
                $query = $this->Connection->find('all', [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'Connection.CustId ' => $customer['CustId']
                    ]
                ]);
                $row = $query->all();
                //$this->set('connection', $row->toArray()); //var_dump(count($row->toArray()));

                //***********on boucle dessus pour avoir les inbound par  msgAccountID and msgBody
                $this->loadModel('Outbox'); 
                $credit_today = 0;$credit_week = 0;$credit_lweek = 0;$credit_month = 0; $credit_lmonth = 0;
                if(count($row->toArray()) == 1)
                {
                $array1 = $row->toArray();
                    $connection = $array1[0]->toArray();

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $aujourdhui,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $demain]);
                        $count_jour = $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_jour = (int)$sum[0]->sum;

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweeke]);                        
                        $count_week = $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_week = (int)$sum[0]->sum;   

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekld,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweekle]);
                        $count_lweek = $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_lweek = (int)$sum[0]->sum;  

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                        $count_month = $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_month = (int)$sum[0]->sum;  

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthld,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthle]);
                        $count_lmonth = $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_lmonth = (int)$sum[0]->sum; 




                    $this->set('inbound_jour', $count_jour);                    
                    $this->set('cr_inboud_jour', $credit_jour);                 
                    $this->set('inbound_week', $count_week);                    
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_week', $credit_week);                    
                    $this->set('inbound_lweek', $count_lweek);                  
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_lweek', $credit_lweek);                  
                    $this->set('inbound_month', $count_month);                  
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_month', $credit_month);                  
                    $this->set('inbound_lmonth', $count_lmonth);                    
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_lmonth', $credit_lmonth);

                }else{ //************** le client a plusieurs connections 

                $count_jour = 0;$credit_jour = 0;$count_week = 0;$credit_week = 0;$count_lweek = 0;$credit_lweek = 0;
                $count_month = 0;$credit_month = 0; $count_lmonth = 0;$credit_lmonth = 0;
                    foreach($row->toArray() as $value)
                    {

                        $connection = $value->toArray();

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $aujourdhui,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $demain]);
                        $count_jour += $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_jour += (int)$sum[0]->sum;

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweeke]);                        
                        $count_week += $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_week += (int)$sum[0]->sum;  

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekld,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweekle]);
                        $count_lweek += $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_lweek += (int)$sum[0]->sum; 

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                        $count_month += $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_month += (int)$sum[0]->sum; 

                        $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                        $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthld,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthle]);
                        $count_lmonth += $query->count('*');
                        $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                        $credit_lmonth += (int)$sum[0]->sum;    


                    }

                    $this->set('inbound_jour', $count_jour);                    
                    $this->set('cr_inboud_jour', $credit_jour);                 
                    $this->set('inbound_week', $count_week);                    
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_week', $credit_week);                    
                    $this->set('inbound_lweek', $count_lweek);                  
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_lweek', $credit_lweek);                  
                    $this->set('inbound_month', $count_month);                  
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_month', $credit_month);                  
                    $this->set('inbound_lmonth', $count_lmonth);                    
                    $this->set('credit_inbound_lmonth', $credit_lmonth);
                }


                //****************************
                //***********on boucle dessus pour avoir les outbound par  msgAccountID and msgBody
                $this->loadModel('Inbox');
                if(count($row->toArray()) == 1)
                {

                    $array1 = $row->toArray();
                    $connection = $array1[0]->toArray();

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $aujourdhui,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $demain]);
                    $count_jour = $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_jour = (int)$sum[0]->sum;

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweeke]);                      
                    $count_week = $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_week = (int)$sum[0]->sum;   

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekld,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweekle]);
                    $count_lweek = $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_lweek = (int)$sum[0]->sum;  

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                    $count_month = $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_month = (int)$sum[0]->sum;  

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthld,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthle]);
                    $count_lmonth = $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_lmonth = (int)$sum[0]->sum; 




                    $this->set('outbound_jour', $count_jour);                   
                    $this->set('cr_outboud_jour', $credit_jour);                    
                    $this->set('outbound_week', $count_week);                   
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_week', $credit_week);                   
                    $this->set('outbound_lweek', $count_lweek);                 
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_lweek', $credit_lweek);                 
                    $this->set('outbound_month', $count_month);                 
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_month', $credit_month);                 
                    $this->set('outbound_lmonth', $count_lmonth);                   
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_lmonth', $credit_lmonth);


                }else{
                //var_dump($row->toArray());
                $count_jour = 0;$count_week = 0;$count_weekl = 0;$count_month = 0;$count_lmonth = 0;
                $credit_jour = 0;$credit_week = 0;$credit_weekl = 0;$credit_month = 0;$credit_lmonth = 0;
                    foreach($row->toArray() as $value)
                    {

                        $connection = $value->toArray();
                        $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $aujourdhui,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $demain]);
                    $count_jour += $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_jour += (int)$sum[0]->sum;

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweeke]);                      
                    $count_week += $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_week += (int)$sum[0]->sum;  

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $ceweekld,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $ceweekle]);
                    $count_lweek += $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_lweek += (int)$sum[0]->sum; 

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                    $count_month += $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_month += (int)$sum[0]->sum; 

                    $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $connection['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                    $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthld,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthle]);
                    $count_lmonth += $query->count('*');
                    $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
                    $credit_lmonth += (int)$sum[0]->sum;    


                    }

                    $this->set('outbound_jour', $count_jour);                   
                    $this->set('cr_outboud_jour', $credit_jour);                    
                    $this->set('outbound_week', $count_week);                   
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_week', $credit_week);                   
                    $this->set('outbound_lweek', $count_lweek);                 
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_lweek', $credit_lweek);                 
                    $this->set('outbound_month', $count_month);                 
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_month', $credit_month);                 
                    $this->set('outbound_lmonth', $count_lmonth);                   
                    $this->set('credit_outbound_lmonth', $credit_lmonth);
                }

            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Votre session a expiré, veuillez vous reconnecter!'));
                $this->setAction('login');
            }
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Votre session a expiré, veuillez vous reconnecter!'));
            $this->setAction('login');
        }
    }

    public function oprSmsTraffic(){
        $this->loadModel('Inbox'); 
        $this->loadModel('Outbox');
        $yesterday = strtotime('yesterday midnight');
        $today = strtotime('today midnight'); //on recupère le jour
        $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow midnight');
        $aujourdhui = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $today)); //. ' - Today for example purposes<br />';
        $demain = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $tomorrow));
        $hier = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $yesterday));

        $this_week_start = strtotime("this week midnight");
        $next_week_start = strtotime("next week midnight");
        $ceweekd = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_week_start));
        $ceweeke = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $next_week_start));//******this week end on next week start

        $last_week_start = strtotime("last week midnight");

        $ceweekld = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $last_week_start));
        $ceweekle = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_week_start));

        $this_month_start = strtotime("first day of this month midnight");
        $next_month_start = strtotime("first day of next month midnight");
        $cemonthd = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_month_start));
        $cemonthe = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $next_month_start));//******this month end on next month start

        $last_month_start = strtotime("first day of last month midnight");

        $cemonthld = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $last_month_start));
        $cemonthle = str_replace(' ', '@', date('Y.m.d H:i:s', $this_month_start));//*********last month end on this month start

        $this->set('customer', $this->paginate($this->Customer));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['customer']);


        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $data = $this->request->data;


            if((int)$data['idCheckPHandler_Flt_4'] == 0 ){
                $this->set('operator', 0);
            }else{

                $this->loadModel('Connection');
                $query = $this->Connection->find('all', [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'Connection.CustId ' => (int)$data['operator'],
                    ]
                ]);
                foreach($query as $value){
                    $operator = $value;
                }
                $operator = $operator->toArray();
                $this->set('operator', $operator);

                $query =  $this->Inbox->find('first')->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => $operator['ConAccountid'], 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthld,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthle]);
                $count_lmonth += $query->count('*');
                debug($count_lmonth);

            }
        }else{
            $this->set('operator', 0); $count_month = 0;$credit_month = 0;
            //*******on recherche pour MTN
            $query =  $this->Inbox->find(
                'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
            )->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => 22, 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
            $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
            $count_month = $query->count('*');
            $this->set('count_Imonth',(int)$count_month);
            $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
            $credit_month = (int)$sum[0]->sum;
            $this->set('credit_Imonth',(int)$credit_month);

            $count_month = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Inbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => 22, 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgTo = 800'.$i]);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Imonth_800'.$i,(int)$count_month);
            }
            $count_month = 0;
            //for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Inbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => 22, 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgTo NOT BETWEEN 8000 AND 8009']);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Imonth_autres',(int)$count_month);
            //}

            $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => 22, 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
            $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
            $count_month = $query->count('*');
            $this->set('count_Omonth',(int)$count_month);
            $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
            $credit_month = (int)$sum[0]->sum;
            $this->set('credit_Omonth',(int)$credit_month);

            $count_month = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Outbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => 22, 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgTo = 800'.$i]);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Omonth_800'.$i,(int)$count_month);
            }
            $count_month = 0;
            //for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Outbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => 22, 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgTo NOT BETWEEN 8000 AND 8009']);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Omonth_autres',(int)$count_month);
            //}
            $count_month = 0;
            //*******on recherche pour ORANGE
            $query =  $this->Inbox->find()->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => 5, 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
            $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
            $count_month = $query->count('*');
            $this->set('count_Imonth1',(int)$count_month);
            $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
            $credit_month = (int)$sum[0]->sum;
            $this->set('credit_Imonth1',(int)$credit_month);

            $count_month = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Inbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => 5, 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgTo = 800'.$i]);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Imonth1_800'.$i,(int)$count_month);
            }

            $count_month = 0;
            //for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Inbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Inbox.MsgAccountID ' => 5, 'Inbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Inbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Inbox.MsgTo NOT BETWEEN 8000 AND 8009']);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Imonth1_autres',(int)$count_month);
            //}
            $count_month = 0;
            $query =  $this->Outbox->find()->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => 5, 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
            $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
            $count_month = $query->count('*');
            $this->set('count_Omonth1',(int)$count_month);
            $sum = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('MsgPartCount')])->toArray();
            $credit_month = (int)$sum[0]->sum;
            $this->set('credit_Omonth1',(int)$credit_month);
            $count_month = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Outbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => 5, 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgTo = 800'.$i]);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Omonth1_800'.$i,(int)$count_month);
            }
            $count_month = 0;
            //for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                $query =  $this->Outbox->find(
                    'all', ['fields' => ['MsgTo', 'MsgBodyType', 'MsgAccountID', 'MsgPartCount', 'MsgReceivedTime'],]
                )->where(['Outbox.MsgAccountID ' => 5, 'Outbox.MsgBodyType ' => 0]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgReceivedTime >=' => $cemonthd,'Outbox.MsgReceivedTime <' => $cemonthe]);
                $query->where(['Outbox.MsgTo NOT BETWEEN 8000 AND 8009']);
                $count_month = $query->count('*');
                $this->set('count_Omonth1_autres',(int)$count_month);
            //}

        }
    }

}
```

My screenshot:
[image]

Comment: to me, and I don't know `cakephp` in any form, it looks like you are executing hundreds of queries in the `dashboard` method

Answer (score 0):

As @RamRaider already said, it's most likely due to the sheer amount of queries you're trying to execute. You can verify this by taking a look at the SQL tab of CakePHPs [Debug Tool](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html).

You'll see a fairly high amount of queries. You can also see which queries take a long time to execute.

Other possible solutions are:

- Reducing the amount of queries executed in a controller.
- Using [CakePHP's result caching](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#caching-loaded-results)
- Storing [Aggregated data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_%28data_warehouse%29) in another database or table

The last one requires another script that actually does all of the calculations and selects you're now doing on page request.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185074/1604068) provides more information about data warehousing.